# Non-parametric alternative for one tailed t-test

Tags: statistics, hypothesis-testing

I am new in the field of statistics I have a dataset with 7000 incidents that were processed within x number of days. I took a sample of 400 from the population.

```
ID      closedindays"
"1"     2
"2"     27
"3"     64
"4"     2
"5"     16
"6"     5
"7"     4
"8"     7
"9"     4
"10"    1
"11"    35
"12"    1
"13"    2
"14"    1
"15"    33
"16"    22
"17"    6
"18"    6
"19"    27
"20"    1
"21"    0
"22"    2
"23"    0
"24"    16
"25"    1
"26"    10
"27"    1
"28"    2
"29"    16
"30"    0
"31"    4
"32"    9
"33"    0
"34"    16
"35"    66
"36"    1
"37"    0
"38"    11
"39"    9
"40"    25
"41"    5
"42"    7
"43"    70
"44"    0
"45"    7
"46"    67
"47"    10
"48"    74
"49"    0
"50"    1
"51"    7
"52"    17
"53"    14
"54"    6
"55"    6
"56"    11
"57"    2
"58"    14
"59"    4
"60"    14
"61"    2
"62"    97
"63"    0
"64"    17
"65"    3
"66"    4
"67"    3
"68"    2
"69"    0
"70"    6
"71"    7
"72"    3
"73"    8
"74"    58
"75"    13
"76"    53
"77"    3
"78"    0
"79"    1
"80"    9
"81"    1
"82"    1
"83"    0
"84"    45
"85"    1
"86"    14
"87"    4
"88"    4
"89"    6
"90"    1
"91"    0
"92"    0
"93"    3
"94"    1
"95"    0
"96"    7
"97"    1
"98"    4
"99"    5
"100"   4
"101"   13
"102"   1
"103"   66
"104"   0
"105"   3
"106"   0
"107"   50
"108"   13
"109"   36
"110"   2
"111"   3
"112"   0
"113"   50
"114"   35
"115"   57
"116"   0
"117"   4
"118"   1
"119"   1
"120"   3
"121"   0
"122"   4
"123"   20
"124"   16
"125"   53
"126"   4
"127"   9
"128"   4
"129"   50
"130"   51
"131"   0
"132"   6
"133"   3
"134"   58
"135"   3
"136"   1
"137"   1
"138"   4
"139"   66
"140"   0
"141"   4
"142"   1
"143"   1
"144"   16
"145"   11
"146"   1
"147"   9
"148"   12
"149"   0
"150"   1
"151"   7
"152"   1
"153"   17
"154"   2
"155"   1
"156"   12
"157"   0
"158"   5
"159"   6
"160"   13
"161"   9
"162"   5
"163"   12
"164"   2
"165"   0
"166"   1
"167"   0
"168"   1
"169"   3
"170"   1
"171"   1
"172"   0
"173"   16
"174"   9
"175"   16
"176"   1
"177"   3
"178"   1
"179"   2
"180"   4
"181"   5
"182"   55
"183"   14
"184"   49
"185"   2
"186"   63
"187"   0
"188"   5
"189"   3
"190"   51
"191"   50
"192"   11
"193"   1
"194"   17
"195"   65
"196"   26
"197"   26
"198"   1
"199"   6
"200"   0
"201"   3
"202"   8
"203"   2
"204"   18
"205"   0
"206"   2
"207"   1
"208"   0
"209"   0
"210"   1
"211"   53
"212"   10
"213"   2
"214"   11
"215"   0
"216"   8
"217"   2
"218"   0
"219"   11
"220"   1
"221"   1
"222"   5
"223"   0
"224"   6
"225"   3
"226"   1
"227"   17
"228"   2
"229"   1
"230"   36
"231"   50
"232"   1
"233"   2
"234"   1
"235"   31
"236"   3
"237"   31
"238"   1
"239"   0
"240"   70
"241"   13
"242"   1
"243"   6
"244"   0
"245"   8
"246"   0
"247"   0
"248"   5
"249"   5
"250"   66
"251"   1
"252"   12
"253"   5
"254"   17
"255"   1
"256"   0
"257"   9
"258"   2
"259"   5
"260"   1
"261"   1
"262"   0
"263"   5
"264"   15
"265"   0
"266"   0
"267"   3
"268"   13
"269"   0
"270"   1
"271"   1
"272"   48
"273"   46
"274"   1
"275"   1
"276"   11
"277"   59
"278"   0
"279"   0
"280"   50
"281"   6
"282"   1
"283"   0
"284"   1
"285"   3
"286"   0
"287"   34
"288"   50
"289"   70
"290"   116
"291"   15
"292"   31
"293"   153
"294"   3
"295"   1
"296"   7
"297"   6
"298"   9
"299"   6
"300"   4
"301"   13
"302"   8
"303"   1
"304"   4
"305"   7
"306"   11
"307"   14
"308"   8
"309"   1
"310"   12
"311"   7
"312"   0
"313"   1
"314"   66
"315"   52
"316"   21
"317"   1
"318"   2
"319"   5
"320"   26
"321"   1
"322"   2
"323"   30
"324"   18
"325"   9
"326"   26
"327"   10
"328"   24
"329"   0
"330"   0
"331"   1
"332"   1
"333"   0
"334"   0
"335"   1
"336"   7
"337"   2
"338"   20
"339"   5
"340"   6
"341"   1
"342"   13
"343"   23
"344"   5
"345"   69
"346"   1
"347"   8
"348"   1
"349"   3
"350"   1
"351"   35
"352"   1
"353"   10
"354"   17
"355"   64
"356"   6
"357"   7
"358"   41
"359"   0
"360"   26
"361"   1
"362"   9
"363"   35
"364"   1
"365"   5
"366"   7
"367"   65
"368"   4
"369"   2
"370"   0
"371"   62
"372"   5
"373"   7
"374"   1
"375"   4
"376"   3
"377"   0
"378"   70
"379"   25
"380"   5
"381"   1
"382"   5
"383"   10
"384"   2
"385"   51
"386"   0
"387"   1
"388"   4
"389"   72
"390"   73
"391"   8
"392"   3
"393"   2
"394"   70
"395"   10
"396"   3
"397"   2
"398"   2
"399"   26
"400"   56
```

The population and sample seems to have a right-skewed distribution.

**What is my hypothesis?**

My hypothesis is that tickets are processed within 14 days on average. I made the following hypothesis:

H0: <= 14
H1: > 14

The problem is that my data is not normally distributed. Because of this I don't think i can do the one tailed Student's t-test. Is this true? Which test can i use?

Comment: Wilcoxon Signed Rank Test is what you’re looking for

Comment: @VishaalSudarsan - wouldn't that be be for comparing two samples?

Comment: @Henry You can do a one-sample Wilcoxon Signed Rank Test as well.

Comment: @VishaalSudarsan That would be a median test rather than a mean test, particularly on a skewed distribution

Comment: That’s right, In non-parametric setup it is usually the median which is used for testing instead of means in parametric testing. For example ANOVA vs Kruskal Wallis test

Comment: @VishaalSudarsan, so the conclusion is that there is no other alternative test for the mean?

Comment: This would be a better question for [CrossValidated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: @coverbook I am not sure about that, all I’m saying is that if you’re fine testing the median then you can use the Wilcoxon Signed ranked test. And yes as galen pointed out you might get better help at CrossValidated.

Comment: @Galen Not necessarily. This is on topic on both sites.

Comment: @StubbornAtom I agree that it is *on topic* for both sites, but given what is being asked, I feel that CrossValidated is a better fit. I'm not flagging the post.

Answer (score 2):

To test $H_0: \eta = 14$ against $H_a: \eta > 14,$ where $\eta$ is the population median, it seems reasonable to
use a one-sided, one-sample Wilcoxon test.

Here is a test of simulated data using that test in R statistical software.

```
set.seed(2020)
x = floor(rgamma(400, 3, .15))
summary(x)
   Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
   1.00   11.00   17.00   19.11   25.00   64.00 
wilcox.test(x, mu=14, alt="greater")

        Wilcoxon signed rank test 
        with continuity correction
data:  x
V = 53250, p-value = 2.178e-15
alternative hypothesis: 
  true location is greater than 14
```

With P-value very nearly $0,$ the null hypothesis is rejected.

Here is a histogram and a boxplot of my data.

```
par(mfrow=c(1,2))
  hist(x, prob=T, col="skyblue2")
  boxplot(x, col="skyblue2", pch=19)
    abline(h = 14, col="green3")
par(mfrow=c(1,1))
```

[image]

Of course, your data are different from my simulated
data, so your result about rejecting the null hypothesis
may differ from mine.